# how to sort 2D Array according to values in any given column in golang?

Tags: sorting, go, matrix, multidimensional-array

We are given a 2D array of order N X M and a column number K ( 1<=K<=m).  Task is to sort the 2D array according to values in the Column K.

```
 Input : If our 2D array is given as (Order 4X4) 
        39 27 11 42 
        10 93 91 90 
        54 78 56 89 
        24 64 20 65
        Sorting it by values in column 3 
Output : 39 27 11 42 
         24 64 20 65 
         54 78 56 89 
         10 93 91 90
```

I think in this task need to use Sort Slice: Len, Less, Swap in Interface but I can't figure out exactly how

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just use `sort.Slice`, which will sort the rows of your 2D slice row by row.

`sort.Slice` takes a function to compare each row against eachother. Inside this function you can compare the column in each row.

https://go.dev/play/p/cj1z7jBs2u5

```
data := [][]int{
    {39, 27, 11, 42},
    {10, 93, 91, 90},
    {54, 78, 56, 89},
    {24, 64, 20, 65},
}
sortCol := 3
sort.Slice(data, func(i, j int) bool {
    return data[i][sortCol] < data[j][sortCol]
})
```

---

If you have an array instead of a slice, then you can use the same `sort.Slice` as above, but use `data[:]` instead of `data`.

https://go.dev/play/p/KcZepTz8SOZ